# Transferring variable's data from one class to another

Tags: python

So I recently started experimenting with oop's and getting the hang of them but I encountered a problem, when the functions from the class "character" are  called from the function "dsiplay" only the first function(set_character_type) is excuted and then the program stops without excuting the rest of the functions, I tried deleting the if statements in the character class it did work but that defeats the point of the program, so am still wondring why does the rest of the code in the "display" function" isn't excuted. what I want is depending on the difficulty chosen from the "set_difficulty" function to determine the stats for the the player's character.

```
from random import randint

class Game_Functions:
    
    def __init__(self,pop,dif):
     self.pop=pop
     self.dif=dif
    
    def Set_Difficulty(self):
        self.pop=input("Please chose your difficulty (Easy/Hard): ")
        if self.pop.capitalize()=="Easy":
            print("You chose the easy difficulty")
            self.dif=True
        elif self.pop.capitalize()=="Hard":
            print("You chose the hard difficulty")
            self.dif=False

class Character(Game_Functions):
    def __init__(self,swordsman,archer,health,attack,defense):
        self.swordsman=swordsman
        self.archer=archer
        self.health=health
        self.attack=attack
        self.defense=defense

    def __init__(self, pop, dif):
        super().__init__(pop, dif)

    def Set_Character_type(self,message):
        message=input("Please Choose your Character type (Swordsman/Archer): ")
        if message.capitalize()=="Swordsman":
            self.swordsman=True
            self.archer=False
            print("You have chosen swordsman class")
        elif message.capitalize()=="Archer":
            self.archer=True
            self.swordsman=False
            print("You have chosen archer class")
        else:
            print("Invalid Input")
    
    def Set_Character_health(self):
        if self.dif==True:
            if self.archer==True or self.swordsman==False:
                self.health=randint(1,12)
                print("The character's health is",self.health)
            elif self.archer==False or self.swordsman==True:
                self.health=randint(1,18)
                print("The character's health is",self.health)
        if self.dif==False:
            if self.archer==True or self.swordsman==False:
                self.health=randint(1,6)
                print("The character's health is",self.health)
            elif self.archer==False or self.swordsman==True:
                self.health=randint(1,9)
                print("The character's health is",self.health)
    
    def Set_Character_attack(self):
        if self.dif==True:
            if self.archer==True or self.swordsman==False:
                self.attack=randint(6,24)
                print("The character's attack is",self.attack)
            elif self.archer==False or self.swordsman==True:
                self.attack=randint(12,17)
                print("The character's attack is",self.attack)
        if self.dif==False:
            if self.archer==True or self.swordsman==False:
                self.attack=randint(3,14)
                print("The character's attack is",self.attack)
            elif self.archer==False or self.swordsman==True:
                self.attack=randint(6,9)
                print("The character's attack is",self.attack)

    def Set_Character_defense(self):
        if self.dif==True:
            if self.archer==True or self.swordsman==False:
                self.defense=randint(5,10)
                print("The character's defense is",self.defense)
            elif self.archer==False or self.swordsman==True:
                self.defense=randint(4,11)
                print("The character's defense is",self.defense)
        if self.dif==False:
            if self.archer==True or self.swordsman==False:
                self.defense=randint(2,6)
                print("The character's defense is",self.defense)
            elif self.archer==False or self.swordsman==True:
                self.defense=randint(3,8)
                print("The character's defense is",self.defense)

def Welcome_Message():
    pop=Game_Functions("","")
    pop.Set_Difficulty()

def display():
    dis=Character("","")
    dis.Set_Character_type("")
    dis.Set_Character_attack()
    dis.Set_Character_defense()
    dis.Set_Character_health()

Welcome_Message()

display()
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by 'when I call the functions from the class "Character" they don't print out'. It would be helpful if you could edit your question to tell us what you tried, what happened, and what you expected/want to happen

Comment: What was there that you tried to "work around"?

Comment: `Character` having 2  `__init__` functions is going to cause you problems. Did you mean to use `super.__init()__` for the second?

Comment: Also, don't use `pop` for a variable, as you run the risk of shadowing the built-in `pop()` function and causing problems

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would help us understand your problem if you show (not just describe) what output you get, as well as what output you expect. See [MRE] for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dif` is set to an empty String in your Character Object

```
dis=Character("","")
```

So when you get to these methods, dif is neither true nor false.

```
dis.Set_Character_attack()
dis.Set_Character_defense()
dis.Set_Character_health()
```

I tried to debug it with adding an arbitrary True to Character initialization like this `dis=Character("",True)` and it works.

pass the Game_Functions objec to your display function

```
def Welcome_Message():
    pop=Game_Functions("","")
    pop.Set_Difficulty()
    return pop



def display(pop):
    dis=Character("", pop.dif)
    dis.Set_Character_type("")
    dis.Set_Character_attack()
    dis.Set_Character_defense()
    dis.Set_Character_health()

pop = Welcome_Message()

display(pop)
```

Comment: Also as @G.Anderson recommended,try to a different variable name instead of ```pop```